# Find an infinite loop in a very big project in Unity

Tags: unity, debugging

How can I find an infinite loop in a very big project in Unity?

I tried to use breakpoints in MonoDevelop and debug, but I was not able to track the loop. I tried to put `Debug.Log()` in a few places and it did not help as well.

So, are there are any other ways of doing it?

It is possible that the loop is not a problem, but I think it is very unlikely. The problem is that when I perform some actions the Unity Editor just stucks and becomes unresponsive at all and I should disable it through the task manager.

Comment: Do you have any editor scripts in Editor folder? That might be causing the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by find an infinite loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a paid ($15) asset called [Panic Button](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/panic-button-40167) that can help you track this down.

You import it into your project, then run. Once Unity locks up in an infinite loop, hit `Shift+Esc` to break out of it and get a stack trace of exactly where execution was stuck. This also resumes editing without crashing, so you don't lose unsaved work.

I don't have any affiliation with the creator, but I can confirm it performs as advertised and doesn't introduce undesirable side-effects into the project. For the price of the coffee I'd have burned through tracking down a few of these issues, I'd personally say it's worthwhile. ;)

Comment: Holy moly, I want this asset now! Hmm, gotta make a free version of it...